# What does the c# Class type declaration say?

Tags: c#, class, definition

```
Class ObjName = new Class();
```

*This question is related* to the fact that i tumbled over a definition as follows:

```
public class Thing{
// Stuff
}
public class Animal:Thing{
// Stuff
}
```

Followed by this declaration `Thing x = new Animal();`

**Related question:** How is the first class definition/type related to the second (after the new keyword)?

[Link to the related article, by: Matthew Cochran](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory2B01142006125918PM/csharp_memory2B.aspx)

Comment: second example is the definition. first is the declaration. They're different, and you should read to understand the difference.

Comment: If I understand the question: The Animal class inherits from Thing, so new Animal() object can be assigned to Thing x reference.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson dear Andreas, there are thousands of resources on Google describing what the classes are and how to declare them. Furthermore, there are hundreds of video tutorials on YouTube with people going over the basics of Object Oriented Programming. Good luck!

Comment: OK, +3 years and now i really know! :D THX 4 the help, still i think its a good newbie question why the class definition is a little "weird" on inheritance, and its not explained in the start of you c# career!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Class ObjName = new Class();` creates an object of type `Class` calling the default constructor and assigns a reference that points to this object to the variable `objName`.

Furthermore this `Thing x = new Animal();` does exactly the same thing (it creates an object and a assigns a reference to this object to a variable). However, here there is a *slight difference*. An `Animal` object is a `Thing` object. In other words, `Animal` inherits `Thing`. So a reference to an `Animal` object can be assigned to a variable, whose type is `Thing`.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) is a nice link for inheritance.

Comment: So, whats actually happens is a declaration as: Animal x = new Animal();? Just that the type of x is that one of the baseclass ...... Which also the Animal class is type off!? :/

Comment: @AndreasJohansson Correct. There happens the two things mentioned above. First an object is created and second a reference to this object is assigned to the variable `x`. Nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

If I am guessing your meaning correctly...

```
public class Thing{
}
public class Animal:Thing{
}
```

This is saying the class Animal derives from class Thing. (Animal : Thing). So if you filled it out a bit more...

```
public class Thing{
  void DoStuff()
  {
     Console.Write("Doing Stuff");
  }
}
public class Animal:Thing{

}
```

you can do things like this...

```
var ani = new Animal();
ani.DoStuff();
```

Because of [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

EDIT: For your benefit in the terms used because they can be difficult enough for beginners (and experts), this would a class definition

```
public class Thing
{
  void DoStuff()
  {
    Console.Write("Doing Stuff");
  }
}
```

This would be a variable declaration (this is not as common today as it was a few years ago, at least in c# and related languages)

```
Thing x;
```

These are variable declaration and assignments - also called "instantiation" as we are creating an instance of the class definition. Using `var` here is a nice shortcut and you should consider using it more than specifying the type on the left side unless there is a compelling reason to do so.

```
var x = new Animal();
var y = new Thing();
```

Comment: Yes, inheritance of a single definition i understand. Now, reference to the base class and then make an instance of a subclass was something new i can't relate or find information about!

Comment: c# does not support multiple inheritance, so a single class is all a single class can inherit from. However they can be chained together DerivedTwo: DerivedOne, DerivedOne:Base. Then anything accessible in DerivedOne and Base is available to DerivedTwo.